# Animated jquery and css slider button

Tags: jquery, button, css-transitions

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this animation http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedButtons/index4.html
but not expand until the arrow is clicked on. I've searched on here and found a few ways of doing it close to this but it seems to get messed up when I add styles to them.
Any pointers would be nice or a good breakdown of how it can be achieved.

Comment: only way you will get pointers is to show what you've tried that comes close. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net. SO is intended to help you with problems in your code. We have no idea what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to change the event from on `mouseover/mouseenter` to on `click` in css 
 here you go,, 
 According to the demo css files - [Demo css](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedButtons/css/style4.css) all you have to do is changing 
`.a-btn:hover` to `.a-btn:active`

Comment: So I've tried to reach the closest thing I would like to achieve.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SplendidAngst/hMcut/3/)
The only 2 issues I'm having is the visible overflow to the left hand side when the button is closed and the open state that the button starts out in.

Comment: Made an update so that the content text doesn't trigger the button to close. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SplendidAngst/hMcut/4/)
And it would be cool if when expanded the + turns into a -

Comment: I did a couple of changes on your css check it and let me know,, here you go, [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/asantarissy/CP6r4/1/)

Comment: Looking at the code changes you made helps makes so much sense, especially with the use of "position:relative" & $(this).find('span').css('background','url("http://psyrax.org/goodies/minus.png") no-repeat 50% 50%') thank you so much!